# jQuery: reading information from a text file and using content in text

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I'm a bit of a newbie to using jQuery and I'm making a graph with `Highcharts`.

I am setting up a function on the loading of the page that refreshes every 5 seconds. During that 5 seconds, I want to add a new point to the chart series. I have no problem when adding one new point to one of the series, but when I try to add all of the points to all of the items in series it won't work.

Code:

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'line',
    events: {
        load: function() {  
            var newdata = [];
            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            setInterval(function() {
               var x = (new Date()).getTime(); // current time
                $.get('newdata.text', function(data) {
                  var lines = data.split("\n");
                  $.each(lines, function(n,elem) {
                    newdata[n] = elem;
                  });
                  chart.series[0].addPoint([x, newdata[0]], false, true);
                  chart.series[1].addPoint([x, newdata[1]], false, true);
                  chart.series[2].addPoint([x, newdata[2]], false, true);
                  chart.series[3].addPoint([x, newdata[3]], false, true);
                  chart.series[4].addPoint([x, newdata[4]], false, true);
                  chart.series[5].addPoint([x, newdata[5]], false, true);
                  chart.series[6].addPoint([x, newdata[6]], false, true); 
                }, "text"); 
              chart.redraw();
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
},
```

The output to the text file is this:

```
107
0.00
0.00
0.00
60
0.00
0.00
```

When I look in the console for this code I get the error that the syntax of the text file is causing an error - note that I am splitting them with `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your value to number, so try to use

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([x, parseFloat(newdata[0])], false, true);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I also saw that I didn't spell the text file correctly, it should have been .txt not .text!